# version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found

Tags: c, linux, debian, gcc

Cuando trato de instalar el programa (./Rack.sh), ,me tira este error:

```
./Rack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 
`GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./Rack)
./Rack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 
`GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./librtaudio.so)
./Rack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 
`GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./librtmidi.so.4)
```

Hice un `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` y me tiro esto:

```
   GLIBCXX_3.4
   GLIBCXX_3.4.1
   GLIBCXX_3.4.2
   GLIBCXX_3.4.3
   GLIBCXX_3.4.4
   GLIBCXX_3.4.5
   GLIBCXX_3.4.6
   GLIBCXX_3.4.7
   GLIBCXX_3.4.8
   GLIBCXX_3.4.9
   GLIBCXX_3.4.10
   GLIBCXX_3.4.11
   GLIBCXX_3.4.12
   GLIBCXX_3.4.13
   GLIBCXX_3.4.14
   GLIBCXX_3.4.15
   GLIBCXX_3.4.16
   GLIBCXX_3.4.17
   GLIBCXX_3.4.18
   GLIBCXX_3.4.19
   GLIBCXX_3.4.20
   GLIBC_2.3
   GLIBC_2.2.5
   GLIBC_2.14
   GLIBC_2.18
   GLIBC_2.17
   GLIBC_2.3.2
   GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Se que es un problema con el `libstdc++.so.6`, tengo que instalar `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` pero no estoy seguro si tengo que instalarlo, en ese caso tengo que hacerlo desde el PPA de Debian, pero por lo que busque no existe, o solo hacer un link simbolico...

Salida `ldd Rack`:

```
./Rack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./Rack)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2ddf8000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc05c060000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fc05bdc6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc05bbc1000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc05b575000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fc05b322000)
libGLEW.so.2.1 => not found
libglfw.so.3 => not found
libjansson.so.4 => not found
libsamplerate.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamplerate.so.0 (0x00007fc05afb4000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fc05ad40000)
libzip.so.5 => not found
librtaudio.so => not found
librtmidi.so.4 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc05aa34000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc05a732000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes de comprobar es que fichero ejecutable (ELF) se llama desde dentro del script **Rack.sh**

Para ver que librerias necesita ese programa simplemente ejecuta el comando **ldd**:

```
$ ldd fichero_ejecutable
```

Ejemplo, para ver las "librerias" que necesita el tar (/bin/tar)

```
$ ldd /bin/tar 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc0259e000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007ffa94d3c000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ffa94b14000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffa94775000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007ffa94570000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ffa942fd000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffa940f9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffa951ac000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffa93edc000)
```

En tu caso parece que se llama al programa: **Rack**, si es así ejecuta:

```
ldd Rack
```

Busca en la salida "not found" para ver que librerias No tienes instaladas

Por cierto puedes indicar que version de Debian usas para facilitarte la instalación/Ajuste de tus librerias...
Lo puedes ver con:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
```

Comment: Hola.. muchas gracias...¡¡..Mi version de Debian es 8.9... este es un tema delicado..asi que voy a necesitar ayuda para no estropear el sistema...

Comment: ok. Y la salida del ldd sobre el binario (rack ó Rack) cual es ??

Comment: Ahi lo puse en el post..